# Do I need new chainring bolts?

Tags: cassette, chainring, compatibility

Will a Race Face 'single' chainring be compatible with a sunrace cassette, taking into account both are designed for 10 speed 1x set-up?
Can I use the same chainring securing bolts as I currently have; being: Shimano SLX 2x set-up?

Thanks,
Cameron

Comment: Since the bolts are meant to keep to rings in place they will leave a gap when fitted with a single ring. You can either get shorter single ring bolts or put washers if no such bolts are available for your cranks.

Comment: @Carel This is a different question than singlespeeding a road double or mountain triple. The OP's crank has a set of bolts for each ring. They're installing a narrow-wide ring with a thick section at the bolt holes and they're presumably asking whether the bolts they've got will be long enough for it.

Comment: Thanks fellas, after a bit of research I found that the Race Face ring bolts must be 8.5 mm of thread. Luckily, the _outer_ ring bolts from the shimano are actually 8.5 mm. So, when my new ring arrives, I expect it to work??? :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As long as you have a ten speed chain it should be fine.
2. Presuming this is FC-M675 or FC-M677, use the 8.5mm bolts from the inner ring. The 7mm ones from the outer are below Race Face's [recommended bolt length](http://www.raceface.com/media/Narrow_wide_ring_installation_guide.pdf).